# How to get database backup using artisan command via controller code?

Tags: database, backup, laravel-5.5, restore

how to get DB backup via controller code using artisan command.
I am using https://github.com/schickling/laravel-backup

this package to backup/restore database.

That package works fine in the terminal with this command `php artisan db:back --database=mysql`  but when i try to execute via the controller code, it doesn't work and this is my code snipped-

```
 try{

  $result=  Artisan::call('db:backup',['--database'=>'mysql']);//this is command
    if($result){
        return Redirect::back()->with('success','Database backup was successful, .SQL file was saved in dump folder.');
    }else{
        return Redirect::back()->with('error','Error to back up database.');
    }
```

I also try with this code but doesn't work

```
Artisan::call('db:backup',['--database'=>'mysql']);
Artisan::call('db:backup');
```

Please, anyone, help me out exactly where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

// start the backup process

```
        Artisan::call('backup:run');
        $output = Artisan::output();
```

// log the results
            Log::info("Backpack new backup started from admin interface \r\n" . $output);

Answer (score 0):

For Automatically Laravel Database backup. my experience for created custom command. and schedule cron job for  24 hour for database backup.

Because I am working project it databse size apporx 24Gb and every day increase 20-30 mb data.

Most important thing is that when you are database dump then not use direct mysql command using **I/O** command because when you use direct mysql dump command
site **slow** when database backup is running this type of issue i have facing
then after surfing and analysis in internet i have create custom databse command using **I/O** command

You can also direct use cmd but it **security** purpose you have to create custom command and fire database backup.
Create custom Command Path :app/Console/Commands/DBBackup.php

```
   <?php
    
    
    
    namespace App\Console\Commands;
    
    
    
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;
    
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
    
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class DBBackup extends Command

{

    /**

     * The name and signature of the console command.

     *

     * @var string

     */

    protected $signature = 'db:backup';

    /**

     * The console command description.

     *

     * @var string

     */

    protected $description = 'Backup the database';

    protected $process;

    /**

     * Create a new command instance.

     *

     * @return void

     */

    public function __construct()

    {

        parent::__construct();

        $fileName='sample_'.date("Y-m-d").'.sql';

        

        

         $this->process = new Process(sprintf(

            'mysqldump -u%s -p%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s  > %s',

            config('database.connections.mysql.username'),

            config('database.connections.mysql.password'),

            config('database.connections.mysql.database'),

            '--single-transaction',

            '--quick',

            '|',

            'ionice',

            '-c2',

            '-n',

            '7',

            'tee',

            storage_path('backups/'.$fileName)

        ));

        

     

    }



    /**

     * Execute the console command.

     *

     * @return mixed

     */

    public function handle()

    {

         try {

            $this->process->setTimeout(null);

            $this->process->setIdleTimeout(null);

            $this->process->mustRun();

            $this->info('The backup has been proceed successfully.');

        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {

            $this->error('The backup process has been failed.');

        }

    }

}
```

Set cron using below command

```
17 20 * * * php {your project pull path}/artisan db:backup >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Sample

```
17 20 * * * php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan db:backup >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Please check this link for full details description : [Laravel Database Backup using laravel command without minimum mysql dump load](https://myphpinformation.blogspot.com/2024/01/laravel-database-backup-using-laravel-command-without-minimum-mysql-dump-load.html)